# Fatal exception is thrown in Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to call other Activity, but it is throwing exception. Here is the code:

```
public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, boolean answerIsTrue) {
    Intent i =  newIntent(packageContext, answerIsTrue);//This line throwing exception
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
    return i;
};
```

And the Logcat here:

```
08-29 05:05:52.061 2457-2457/com.bbn.geoquiz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bbn.geoquiz, PID: 2457
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at com.bbn.geoquiz.CheatActivity.newIntent(CheatActivity.java:17)
at
08-29 05:05:53.550 2457-2457/com.bbn.geoquiz E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 17527860)
08-29 05:05:53.550 2457-2457/com.bbn.geoquiz E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 17527860 bytes
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4425)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Could you advise please how to fix this error?

Comment: `Intent i =  newIntent(packageContext, answerIsTrue);` where `new Intent(#Context, #Class);` but you are passing boolean

Comment: Where you should be passing the class name instead of passing boolean as second parameter

Comment: @Sanoop, thanks, let me try to change signature.

Comment: Let me know if it worked.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are causing infinite loop, code should be:

```
public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, Class<?> clazz, boolean answerIsTrue) {
    Intent i =  new Intent(packageContext, clazz);
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the public constructors for `Intent`

```
Intent()
```

Create an empty intent.

```
Intent(Intent o)
```

Copy constructor.

```
Intent(String action)
```

Create an intent with a given action.

```
Intent(String action, Uri uri)
```

Create an intent with a given action and for a given data url.

```
Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

Create an intent for a specific component.

```
Intent(String action, Uri uri, Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

Create an intent for a specific component with a specified action and data.

**`In your case you are passing boolean as the second parameter, where you need to pass the class name as the second parameter`**

Comment: _In your case you are passing boolean as the second parameter,..._ --- He is calling his own implementation of `newIntent`, repeatedly. That's the reason for `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the same method recursively without stopping at the mentioned line.

```
Intent i =  newIntent(packageContext, answerIsTrue);
```

Please fix the logic in your code flow.